# Wildcard .dev URLs on virtual machine (windows <> Ubuntu)

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, vmware-workstation, wildcard

The past few days I'm exploring how to setup a webserver (personal usage).. I'm a programmer not a sysadmin, so it's a lot trial and error for me.

What I have so far:

VM Workstation

- Host: Windows 7
- Guest: Ubuntu 11.04

  - apache, MySQL, PHP, bind9, etc.
  - samba file sharing
  - webmin

My goal is to create a wildcard `.dev` domain available from my host machine (Windows 7) pointing to a virtual host on the guest machine (Ubuntu).

So for instance; I enter `www.domain.com.dev` in a web browser on Windows 7, this should resolve to `/var/www/sites/domain.com/www/htdocs` on the virtual Ubuntu server.

I'm known with `VirtualDocumentRoot` so thats not going to be the problem but I'm clueless about the DNS configuration (especially to make it available on windows).

Answer (score 2):

You would do that in your hosts file. This tells you how to edit that: 
http://www.windowsreference.com/windows-7/edit-hosts-file-in-windows-7-windows-vista/

You cannot use wildcards in the hostsfile, so you will have to add each site individually, but it takes like 1 minute to add something once you got figured out how it works :)

You need the IP address of your guest machine. issue "/sbin/ifconfig" in your vm to find that. Also, the easiest way to get this to work networkwise is to have the network adapter in your virtual machine set to "Bridged Mode" - this way it will retrieve an IP address via DHCP from your local network. (I am assuming you have a standard home network with a DHCP router).

When you have the IP, open the hosts file and add entries. In my example the IP address of the VM is 192.168.1.20

```
192.168.1.20    mywebsite.dev www.mywebsite.dev
192.168.1.20    anothersite.dev www.anothersite.dev
```

This will cause mywebsite.dev, www.mywebsite.dev, anothersite.dev and www.anothersite.dev to hit the IP address of the VM.

Comment: It's bridged, if i hit http://GUEST-IP on windows it resolves to the current document root on ubuntu, which is nice. I can setup wildcard dns on ubuntu with bind9 right? So then i only have to maintain the windows hosts file... which is... ok =)

Comment: You don't need BIND on the Ubuntu machine to take care of virtual hosts, those are handled in Apache.

Comment: I got it working on ubuntu with dnsmasq; pointing *.dev to 127.0.0.1. For now i will manually maintain the windows hosts file with domain names i often use.